# Suspicious upvotes

Tags: discussion, up-votes

User dannyf gets every day since October upvotes on three to five old answers. That makes around 2400 points in two months.

I flagged the last upvoted answer but the flag was declined maybe because my description of the problem was too short.

EDIT: I noticed it as I visited the Users page and Majenko was not first there as always. (I was on the way to Majeko's profile for the Evils of String link.) So I was curios what good answers the user wrote to get so many points this month.

Comment: @Majenko, the upvotes continue

Answer (score 7):

This has been raised with the powers that be.

---

Update: Your suspicions were correct and the votes have been reversed.

Comment: there is a new case. per1234 gets 3 upvotes on old answers almost every day. I know Per from arduino forum and I am 100% sure he is not doing it. it must be a fan.

Comment: and dannyf again

Comment: now Edgar gets too many upvotes on old questions. somebody is playing with SE

Comment: now Peter Bloomfield has 3 upvotes every day